# Is there a selinux, httpd, or PHP configuration that prevents reading mounted drives?

Tags: security, mount, webserver, selinux

I'm moving a virtualized centos web server over that has an all-to-small hard drive to a new machine and I hooked up a bigger drive for hosting videos and downloads and stuff.  W

When I try to run a readfile or filesize or anything from my PHP script, I get the stat failed error telling me I don't have rights to my file. Everything looks like it should work according to permissions (I can even chmod them 777 all and I get the same problem).

When I put files in the /mnt folder, I can read them, but if I put them in the mounted /mnt/data folder. Other than file/directory level permissions, are there permissions that need to be granted to allow the apache user/group or the httpd service to be able to communicate with mounted drives.

(If this is a security feature, I think it's a great idea, I just need to be able to subvert it in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a SELinux security setting, you have to do the following:

> chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /mnt/data

that code will update the security contexts for everything in your /mnt/data folder.

[more info about SELinux and CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-0f6390ddacfab39ee973ed8018a32212c2a02199)

<sub>Note, I have no idea why this works of what SELinux security contexts are, I just found the answer to my own questions after writing it down, posting it here and thinking a little bit harder about what I should be looking for.</sub>